# There is a problem in the gutenberg block I developed. Problem is with withInstanceId

Tags: plugin-development, block-editor

I  can get a unique id withInstanceId , but I get a bug like this on my block in dev console.

```
Expected:
<div id="deneme-carousel-1" class="owl-carousel owl-theme"></div><script>jQuery( document ).ready( function() { jQuery('#deneme-carousel-1').owlCarousel();</script>
Actual:
<div id="deneme-carousel-21" class="owl-carousel owl-theme"></div><script>jQuery( document ).ready( function() { jQuery('#deneme-carousel-21').owlCarousel();</script>


index.js
    save: withInstanceId( function( { instanceId} ) {
        return(
            <div id={`deneme-carousel-${ instanceId }`} className={ classnames( 'owl-carousel', 'owl-theme', className ) }>
            </div>
            <script>
                {'function() { jQuery(\'#'+`deneme-carousel-${instanceId}`+'\').owlCarousel();'}
            </script>
    } ),
```

Comment: So you're asking why you're being assigned instanceId=21 not instanceId=1? Does that matter? Is that the bug you meant, or is this breaking something else for you?

Comment: gutenberg breaks the block and returns this error. why is my id starting from 1? or why gutenberg gives a mistake. Need to reset id value 
Expected: <div id="deneme-carousel-1" 
Actual: <div id="deneme-carousel-21"
[link](http://prntscr.com/nct3zb)